# JavaCC: How can I make generated boilerplate classes package-private?

Tags: java, package, visibility, conflict, javacc

I know that I can specify the option `SUPPORT_CLASS_VISIBILITY_PUBLIC = false;` inside a `.jj` file. But this makes only the generated class itself package-private.

The "boilerplate" classes (such as `ParseException`) are still public. This is very annoying, since I use `java.text.ParseException` for public exposure of the API.

Any ideas how to make the boilerplate classes also package-private?

Comment: There's no way to do that. What I did was copy the generated boilerplate classes, make them package-private, and from then on discard the newly generated ones. This is quite easy to do in an Ant file or POM.

Comment: My approach (and the now used solution) was different: I wrote delegate classes which for themselves were public, but delegated to private boilerplate classes.